# Why does Stream.foldLeft take two elements before operating?

Tags: scala

foldLeft needs only one element from the collection before operating. So why does it try to resolve two of them? Couldn't it be just a little bit lazier?

```
def stream(i: Int): Stream[Int] = 
  if (i < 100) {
    println("taking")
    i #:: stream(i + 1)
  } else Stream.empty

scala> stream(97).foldLeft(0) { case (acc, i) => 
  println("using")
  acc + i
}

taking
taking
using
taking
using
using
res0: Int = 294
```

I ask this because I have a built a stream around a mutable priority queue, wherein the iteration of the fold can inject new members into the stream. It starts off with one value and during the first iteration injects more values. But those other values are never seen because the stream has already been resolved to `empty` in position 2 before the first iteration.

Comment: A perhaps simpler demonstration: `(1 to 3).toStream.map(x => {println(s"a$x"); x}).foldLeft(()) { case (_, x) => println(s"b$x") }` - prints `a1 a2 b1 a3 b2 b3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can only explain why it's happening. [Here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.scala) is source of stream's `#::` (`Cons`):

```
final class Cons[+A](hd: A, tl: => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A] {
    override def isEmpty = false
    override def head = hd
    @volatile private[this] var tlVal: Stream[A] = _
    @volatile private[this] var tlGen = tl _
    def tailDefined: Boolean = tlGen eq null
    override def tail: Stream[A] = {
      if (!tailDefined)
        synchronized {
          if (!tailDefined) {
            tlVal = tlGen()
            tlGen = null
          }
        }

      tlVal
    }
  }
```

So you can see that `head` is always calculated (isn't lazy). Here is `foldLeft`:

```
override final def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = {
  if (this.isEmpty) z
  else tail.foldLeft(op(z, head))(op)
}
```

You can see that `tail` is called here, which means that "head of tail" (second element) becomes calculated automatically (as it requires your `stream` function to be called again to generate tail). So the better question isn't "why second" - the question is why `Stream` always calculates its **first** element. I don't know the answer, but believe that scala-library's implementation could be improved just by making head `lazy` inside `Cons`, so you could pass `someLazyCalculation #:: stream(i + 1)`.

Note that eitherway your `stream` function will be called twice, but second approach gives you a way to avoid automatical second head's calculation by providing some lazy value as a head. Smthng like this could work then (now it doesn't):

```
def stream(i: Int): Stream[Int] = 
  if (i < 100) {
    lazy val ii = {
      println("taking")
      i
    }
    ii #:: stream(i + 1)
  } else Stream.empty
```

P.S. It's probably not so good idea to build (eventually) immutable collection around mutable one.